# Can I read multiple lines from keyboard with fgets?

Tags: c, stdin, fgets

I am trying to read a few lines from stdin (my keyboard) in C, and I wasn't able to do this.

My input it looks like this:

```
3
first line
second line
third line
```

There's my code:

```
char input[2], s[200];
if (fgets(input, 2, stdin) != NULL) {
    printf("%d\n", input[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i <= input[0] - '0'; i++) {
        if (fgets(s, 20, stdin) != NULL)
            printf("%d\n", s[1]);
    }
}
```

It seems that this function, "fgets" is reading even my new line char, coded with 10 in ASCII.
BTW, I am running my code in linux terminal.

Comment: That's correct, `fget()` reads the newline too (if there is room). That way, you know a complete line was read, not that the buffer was full. The program behaviour is undefined though, because `fgets(s, 20, stdin)` needs a buffer of size 20, not the 2 available in `s[2]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to read a few lines from stdin (my keyboard) in C, and I
> wasn't able to do this.

**Reasons:**

1. `printf("%d\n", input[0]);` This statement prints an extra `\n`, which is read by `fgets` during first iteration. So, `s` will store `\n` in the first iteration. Use `getchar()` to read that extra `\n`.
2. `fgets(s, 20, stdin)` , You are reading 20 bytes, but the input string (second one) occupies more than 20 bytes. Increase it.
3. `printf("%d\n", s[1]);` change to `printf("%s\n", s);`

The code is :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

    char input[2], s[200];
    if (fgets(input, 2, stdin) != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n", (input[0]- '0'));
        getchar();  // to read that extra `\n`
        for (int i = 1; i <= (input[0] - '0'); i++)
        {
            if (fgets(s, 50, stdin) != NULL) // increase from 20 to 50
                printf("%s\n", s);  // printing string
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is :

```
3
3
this is first line
this is first line

this is the second line
this is the second line

this is the third line
this is the third line
```